# Did King Saul lose his salvation?

Tags: 1-samuel, soteriology, saul

King Saul appeared to have had a "born again" experience:

> 9 When he turned his back to leave Samuel, **God gave him another heart**. And all these signs came to pass that day. 10 When they came to Gibeah, behold, a group of prophets met him, **and the Spirit of God rushed upon him, and he prophesied among them**. [1 Samuel 10:9-10 ESV]

But then we are told the following:

> 14 Now **the Spirit of the Lord departed from Saul**, and a harmful spirit from the Lord tormented him. [1 Samuel 16:14 ESV]

> 15 Then Samuel said to Saul, “Why have you disturbed me by bringing me up?” Saul answered, “I am in great distress, for the Philistines are warring against me, and **God has turned away from me** and answers me no more, either by prophets or by dreams. Therefore I have summoned you to tell me what I shall do.” 16 And Samuel said, “Why then do you ask me, since the Lord has turned from you and become your enemy? 17 The Lord has done to you as he spoke by me, **for the Lord has torn the kingdom out of your hand and given it to your neighbor, David**. 18 Because you did not obey the voice of the Lord and did not carry out his fierce wrath against Amalek, therefore **the Lord has done this thing to you this day**. 19 Moreover, the Lord will give Israel also with you into the hand of the Philistines, **and tomorrow you and your sons shall be with me**. The Lord will give the army of Israel also into the hand of the Philistines.” [1 Samuel 28:15-19 ESV]

> 4 Then Saul said to his armor-bearer, “Draw your sword, and thrust me through with it, lest these uncircumcised come and thrust me through, and mistreat me.” But his armor-bearer would not, for he feared greatly. **Therefore Saul took his own sword and fell upon it**. 5 And when his armor-bearer saw that Saul was dead, he also fell upon his sword and died with him. 6 **Thus Saul died**, and his three sons, and his armor-bearer, and all his men, on the same day together. [1 Samuel 31:4-6 ESV]

Did King Saul lose his salvation?

Comment: I do not know how final judgement will play out for Saul, but I am grateful for the fact that I will not be his judge.

Comment: Just having spiritual gifts does not save a man. Where do we read of Saul being 'saved'. Or, from what was he 'saved' ? Though I speak with the tongue of men and angels, and have prophecy and understand all mysteries and all knowledge : yet without real love to God and to one's brethren (to David, for example, whom Saul hated) one is nothing. Absolutely nothing. (Up-voted +1.)

Comment: @NigelJ - we are told that God changed his heart (1 Samuel 10:9), so there is that.

Comment: Indeed, but did God 'give him a new heart' ? Or was the old heart just changed in some way, to adjust to his responsibilities of office ?

Comment: @NigelJ - technically the verse says "God gave him another heart", so that's a different heart than the one he already had. I would presume that the "other heart" was a new one.

Comment: Many spiritual commentators have pointed to Saul as an example of just how far the old nature can go in religion without real repentance, and without the true knowledge of God, himself, personally. He seems to have everything, yet in the end, all is worthless and Samuel rejects him. And God chooses David.

Comment: Saul hated David and wanted to murder David. And would have done so, had he not been prevented. He that hateth his brother without a cause is a murderer. And no murderer hath eternal life abiding in him. But it's an excellent question and I would vote it up again had I the capacity to do so.

Comment: Saul born again? Where is your foundation for O.T. Saints being ‘born again’?

Comment: @Dave - John 3:5 *"Jesus answered, “Truly, truly, I say to you, **unless one is born of water and the Spirit, he cannot enter the kingdom of God**."*

Comment: Jesus was talking to Nicodemus - a highly educated, Old Testament literate member of the Sanhedrin - and he didn’t have a clue about what Jesus was talking about. Ever wonder why?

Comment: @Dave - you just inspired me to ask this question: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/58805/truly-truly-i-say-to-you-unless-one-is-born-again-he-cannot-see-the-kingdom

Comment: Jesus seemed to speak to Nicodemus as if he expected Nicodemus would understand what he was talking about, but Jesus evidently knew beforehand that he wouldn't understand.  It requires more than literacy and education to understand what Jesus was talking about.  Jesus was making a point, but the point was lost on Nicodemus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this question is definitively answerable because we cannot know the judgements of God.  However, the evidence is compelling:

- Saul wan anointed with oil and consecrated for a special task, 1 Sam 10:1
- Saul was given a "new heart", 1 Sam 10:9
- Saul had the gift of the Holy Spirit, 1 Sam 10:9
- Saul prophesied, 1 Sam 10:10, 12
- Saul used the power of the God's Spirit at other times, 1 S6am 11:6
- Saul was initially kind and generous, 1 Sam 11:13

But Saul, slowly turned his back on God and returned to his old habits and became self-centered, narcissistic and paranoid.  He wanted to murder David, was very impatient (1 Sam 14), became depressed and ultimately sank so low that he consulted a witch and then committed suicide.

We cannot know Saul's "heart" at the end and what God will do with Saul at the resurrection.  So the question cannot be finally answered until Jesus reveals all things.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 Samuel 10:10 When they came to Gibeah, behold, a group of prophets met him, and the Spirit of God rushed **upon** him, and he prophesied among them.

Note that the Spirit was not **in** him.

> 1 Samuel 16:14 Now the Spirit of the Lord **departed** from Saul, and a harmful spirit from the Lord tormented him.

Did King Saul lose his salvation?

It depends on how you define *salvation*. The word "salvation" does not appear in any of the passages that you have quoted. Saul did lose the Spirit that was given him.

In fact, Saul understood salvation this way:

> 1 Samuel 11:11 The next day Saul organized the troops into three divisions, and during the morning watch they invaded the camp of the Ammonites and slaughtered them, until the hottest part of the day. And the survivors were so scattered that no two of them were left together.
>
> 12Then the people said to Samuel, “Who said that Saul should not reign over us? Bring those men here so we can kill them!”
>
> 13 But Saul ordered, “No one shall be put to death this day, for today the LORD has worked **salvation** in Israel.”

To him, a meaning of salvation was physical deliverance from God.

Comment: What about Saul's change of heart at 1 Samuel 10:9? https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/58216/what-does-it-mean-that-god-gave-saul-another-heart-in-1-samuel-109

Answer (score 0):

The question "*Did King Saul lose his salvation?*" makes a very large assumption.

What reason is there to believe that Saul was ever offered salvation?

In the Hebrew scriptures, "salvation" tends to be of a physical kind, very unlike the salvation that Christians believe in.

It's not possible to lose something that one never had.

Comment: What about Saul's change of heart at 1 Samuel 10:9? https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/58216/what-does-it-mean-that-god-gave-saul-another-heart-in-1-samuel-109

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator, "*God gave him another heart*" simply means a new outlook or understanding of the situation.  Strong's says "*the heart; also used (figuratively) very widely for the feelings, the will and even the intellect*".  There's nothing there to imply salvation.